# Android Studio commands not working on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading MacOS and Android Studio, a lot of the menu and shortcut commands I rely on no longer work. For example Shift-F6 for renaming vars (I tried from the menu and shortcut). Also, things like Cmd-Shift-o to search a list of files. I would expect equivalent menu options to work, but they don't.

Here's my setup:

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Mac Ventura 13.1

Preferences -> Keymap is set to MacOS.

I use an external Logitech Bluetooth keyboard.

I'm a longtime AS user and I have a second, nearly identical setup, with an external keyboard, on another computer, which all works fine.

I've tried all the usual stuff like rebooting and invalidating caches.

I tried reinstalling AS, just the app, not all the settings files, etc.

Before I try to completely wipe out AS, which I'm not sure will work either, I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: "I would expect equivalent menu options to work, but they don't" -- if you choose the menu item, does Studio simply not react, or are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: No reaction from AS, as though it isn't even a menu option. No error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seemed like AS needed a total reset. I found [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013611/how-to-restore-default-setting-android-studio-artic-fox).

To restore the AS default settings:

`File> Manage IDE settings> Restore defaultsettings`

This fixed key mappings that didn't include the FN keys. To get those to work I had to toggle the FN lock button on my keyboard. That button does not turn FN keys on/off, but switches them between different mappings.

Answer (score 3):

You should also press `fn` button if you have one on your keyboard.
Or try to turn it off:

1. Choose Apple menu  > System Settings.
2. Click Keyboard in the
   sidebar.
3. Click the Keyboard Shortcuts button on the right.
4. Click
   Function Keys in the sidebar.
5. Turn on “Use F1, F2, etc. keys as
   standard function keys”.

Comment: Thank your for the response. I forgot to mention the Use F1, F2...as standard function keys option is already turned on and I did press the "fn" button on my keyboard. No dice.